# How to increase body size limit for adapter-node

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Currently I have an action that is working fine when the uploaded file is small. When it gets bigger, like 7MB, I get an error "Invalid request body". How to fix it?

I am using adapter-node.
I've read the docs:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-body-size-limit

But I don't know how to set it. Help Me?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that is only start node with the env variable.

```
BODY_SIZE_LIMIT=20000000 node index.js
```